# Does IE11 still support dispatchEvent/FireElement?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-11

Where I work we have internal page that used to work with VBA, but I guess since last page or IE update it no longer does.
Macro selects country and then press the button to generate a report for that particular country. Problem is that although the name in dropdown menu changes visually, the actual value does not change (onChange event is not being triggered). I have tried changing the .focus to another dropdown, firing/dispatching events, .SendKeys "~", but to no avail.
This is what I have:

```
    Dim document As HTMLDocument: Set document = ieTab.document
    Dim processCnt As HTMLInputElement
    Dim eventObj As Object
    Dim hwndCounter As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 8
        Set processCnt = ElementTimer(3, ieTab)
        
        
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                processCnt.DefaultValue = "London"
            Case 2
                processCnt.Value = "Prague"
            Case 3
                processCnt.Value = "WUIB"
            Case 4
                processCnt.Value = "Zurich"
            Case 5
                processCnt.DefaultValue = "Norway"
            Case 6
                processCnt.Value = "Sweden"
            Case 7
                processCnt.Value = "Poland"
            Case 8
                processCnt.Value = "Russia"
        End Select

Set eventObj = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    eventObj.initEvent "keyup", False, True
    processCnt.dispatchEvent eventObj

Private Function ElementTimer(number As Integer, ieTab As InternetExplorer)
    Dim messageBoxHW As LongPtr
    
    On Error GoTo timer1
1:
        Select Case number
            Case 1
                Set ElementTimer = ieTab.document.getElementsByClassName("rgNoRecords").Item(0)
            Case 2
                ieTab.document.getElementById("gvReport_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ExportToExcelButton").Click
            Case 3
                Set ElementTimer = ieTab.document.getElementById("ProcessCenter_ID_Input")
                If ElementTimer Is Nothing Then GoTo timer1
        End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
timer1:
    DoEvents
    messageBoxHW = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Message from webpage")
    If messageBoxHW > 0 Then SendMessage messageBoxHW, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0
    Resume 1
End Function
```

The value is being changed before this code.
This is the drop-down Im having problems with.

```
            <!-- 2020.3.1021.45 --><table summary="combobox" border="0" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%" class="rcbFocused rcbExpanded">
                <tbody><tr class="rcbReadOnly">
                    <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;"><input name="ProcessCenter_ID" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ProcessCenter_ID_Input" value="United States" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off"></td><td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="ProcessCenter_ID_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table><input id="ProcessCenter_ID_ClientState" name="ProcessCenter_ID_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
```

Does this mean that you can no longer simulate change events? Because it sure looks like it after 2 days of googling and trying. Im out of ideas

"Copy JS Path" yielded this: document.querySelector("#ProcessCenter_ID")

To be honest I don't know how to identify the exact JS that is being initiated upon changing the value of a drop-down

Comment: Is there any error when it doesn't work? Could you please provide the complete related code with the dropdown menu so that we can have a test? Besides, I noticed that there's a `readonly` attribute in the `<input>` which means you can't edit it. You can also try to remove the `readonly` attribute to see if this can fix the issue.

Comment: I've added the code that selects value from drop-down. Any ideas how to initiate that change event?

Comment: It seems that there's some misunderstanding. I mean the related **html** and **javascript** code about the dropdown menu. It's an internal page and we can't have a test with a link. So I want to check the html structure and check how the event is fired in the original page.

Comment: I've added to the original question, but I dont think it will be of any help since I can not identify the script that is being called once the changes are made.

Comment: You're right. It seems nothing special with the html code. It's hard to debug without having access to the website. I can only provide some information about firing `onchange` event. You can refer to [this article](https://codedocu.com/office-365/Access/Controls/web-Browser/Vba,-HTMLSelect_colon_-FireEvent-OnChange-or-DispatchEvent?1890) about dispatching the `onchange` event. Please pay attention to that it should be *objEvent.initEvent "change", **True, False***.